# Survey tool to assign options

Tags: web-services, survey

I am looking for a software or service with which users can grab tasks independently.

An admin should be able to define several options (e.g. tasks or appointments).
Then it should be possible to send this as a link to a group, and each recipient can assign one or more options by entering their name.
If an option is assigned, this name appears for other recipients at the selected option and is then blocked for other recipients.

The interface is similar to doodle.com, but I don't want to find a common appointment but distribute many tasks.

### Example Party BYO

| Food | Who |
| --- | --- |
| Fingerfood | Jon |
| Muffins |  |
| Cake |  |
| Soda | Mike |
| Lemonade |  |
| Coffee | Anna |

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I am one of the developers of PollUnit.

[PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) allows you to create a [voting](https://pollunit.com/en/voting) with the target "best distribution" (which can be selected in the first step of the wizard). You have the flexibility to incorporate various options, allowing participants to choose one or more selections. In the default setup, multiple individuals can endorse the same option, with the system adeptly distributing options across all participants. If you opt for a rating mechanism like star voting, the system's goal is to provide each participant with an option they have rated positively.

Additionally, you can implement limitations on the number of participants per option. For instance, only one user may select a particular option. However, it's important to note that the limitation feature is part of our premium plans.

You can also enable participants to add their own options, which can be particularly useful in scenarios like creating a list of food items.